# How to determine UIButton was pressed?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton

I am trying to make a simple app for my kid.

The next step is

1. Detect what `UIButton` was pressed.
2. Assign to an empty array the value of the specific array of that
   button

I have two buttons for the moment (totally there will be 20+)

```
@IBAction func tapLA(sender: UIButton) {
}

@IBAction func tapLB(sender: UIButton) {
}
```

both of them are connected with `PageViewController` that has arrays of images

```
// the array
private var contentImages = ["",
                             "",
                             "",
                             ""]

//the array of gallery images lettera A
private let contentImagesA = ["letteraA",
                              "ape",
                              "albero",
                              "arcobaleno"]


// the array of gallery immages lettera B
private let contentImagesB = ["letteraB",
                              "barca",
                              "balena",
                              "banana"]
```

I need to show different array depending on what button was tapped, but I have no idea how to do that.
In poor words it should be:

if button A is pressed, show images of array A

if button B is pressed, show images of array B.

Comment: I don't how your UI is? why can't you use UICollectionView instead of UIButton.

Comment: I have created an UICollectionView, it was a very nice suggestion. Thank you! Now I'm stuck in getting the cell index: 1. I have created a var letterIndex: Int = 0 ... 2. then in the function didSelectItemAtIndex I assign letterIndex=indexPath.row, but then in another view controller where I want to have this number, it doesn't see it and it gives me "unresolved identifier"

Comment: You can set a variable like selectedIndex in your SecondViewController and set value for it in performSegueWithIdentifier method.

Answer (score 1):

When button is selected run the method that loads pictures

```
@IBAction func tapLA(sender: UIButton) {
    openPicturesFrom(contentImagesA)
}

func openPicturesFrom(arr: Array) {
    //here you have array and you can start opening pictures
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow this approach:
In your first controller define all arrays.

```
 // define globally
   var imageDictinary = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()
   var imageArray:[String] = Array()
```

in your `viewDidLoad` or intializing method

```
imageDictinary = [1:["letteraA","ape","albero","arcobaleno"],
                  2:["letteraB","barca","balena","banana"],
                  // and so on..
                  ]
```

Add buttons with Tags from 1 to 26 (No of array in dictionary). Assign `onButtonClick` method to all button actions.

```
@IBAction func onButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    let images:Array = imageDictinary[sender.tag]!;
     imageArray = images
     openPageController()
 }

 openPageController(){
    // open page controller here programatically
    }

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let page:PageViewController  = segue.destinationViewController as! PageViewController
        page.images = imageArray
    }
```

Here you only have to write code for opening `pageController` to  one button Action. Open it using seague.

Every time you click particular button, its corresponding array will be assigned to `imageArray` which you can use through out the code.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be using a `Dictionary` containing your arrays as values and then some sort of ID for keys (you can read more about `dictionaries` in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113]))

So you could do something like:

```
let content = ["buttonA" : ["letteraA",
                            "ape",
                            "albero",
                            "arcobaleno"],
               "buttonB" : ["letteraB",
                            "barca",
                            "balena",
                            "banana"]]
```

In your "button actions", you would then fetch the right array from the key and then call a method that would do whatever you'd like to do with that array onwards:

```
@IBAction func tapLA(sender: UIButton) {
   if let aArray = content["buttonA"] {
       populateAndDoYourMagicHere(withArray: bArray)
   }
}

@IBAction func tapLB(sender: UIButton) {
   if let bArray = content["buttonB"] {
       populateAndDoYourMagicHere(withArray: bArray)
   }
}

func populateAndDoYourMagicHere(withArray array: [String]) {
       contentImages = array
       //do your magic here
}
```

Hope that makes sense and helps you.